# Where to set app "compatibility" in Apple App Store listing (left side bar)?

Tags: app-store

I was reading Apple documentation and all I could find is how to de-list certain features like Bluetooth which would in turn make the app unavailable for some devices. But where is the setting for "compatibility" that actually appears on App Store?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think 3 factors can influence this

- Targeted devices (iPad apps only)
- your devices [required capabilities](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html)
- the targeted minimal OS (see this [matrix](http://iossupportmatrix.com/))

You can not specifically declare supported devices
Nicolas

Comment: So, if I wanted to Appstore to show only iPhone as compatible devices, I should set UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in my info.plist ?

Comment: Actually this is done in the pbxproj file using the `TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY` key. You can change that directly in the GUI in the General section of your target https://i.imgur.com/rYMkbvC.png. Note that an iPhone app will always be available in the App Store for iPad users and will launch in compatibility mode

Comment: Hi Nicolas,
Unfortunately i have committed the same mistake. Now i want my app to only support iPhone for the next release.
So i tried changing project pbx. This lead to error some ITMS - 90001 and didn't let me submit  the app.
I have to change back to original setting as before to submit the app.
Please help me to support my app for iPhone only.
Thanks in advance.