# How to change device compatibility of iphone app on App store?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, app-store

Our company has two app. One's device target is iOS 9 (let say "first app") and the other one's is iOS 8.1 (let say "second app") . When we upload to App Store, compatibility for "first app" is shown as below. [image]

But for "second app", it shows as 
[image]

Please help me figure out how to make second app's compatibility to show as same as first one's. And why it isn't compatible for all iPhone devices?

Comment: Are you trying to get the second app to only be compatible with iOS 9.0 or are you trying to change the device list while keeping it at 8.1? I don't think the latter is actually possible. For what it's worth, the first app isn't compatible for all iPhone devices either because not all iPhones can upgrade to iOS 9.0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to set app "compatibility" in Apple App Store listing (left side bar)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33914387/where-to-set-app-compatibility-in-apple-app-store-listing-left-side-bar)

Comment: I'm trying to change device list while keeping it at 8.1. My boss wants to show both app with same compatibility. And I'm very new to check for it, I don't know how to do. :(

Comment: It looks like your second app may be missing 32 bit support since iPhone 4 is missing

Comment: @Paulw11 how do I add 32 bit support?

Comment: Make sure you target arm as well as armv7

Comment: Yes, I set armv7 for both apps.

Comment: Can you please answer this question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50758089/how-appstore-device-compatibility-worksa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key and its array (values) from the **info.plist** file.

[image]

I know i'll have specific devices (like your problem) when I found the build supports only `arm64`
[image]

Now, after removing `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key and its array,
I got this build info

[image]

Comment: Can you please answer this question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50758089/how-appstore-device-compatibility-works

Comment: Hey, after releasing my app its target ios 13 and up, so is there way to change it?