# How to edit APP compatibility information when IOS is released

Tags: ios, compatibility

I find my newer upload app compatibility information in appstore is *"compatible with iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch"*, but I just want to be compatible with iPhone, what should I do? Thanks.

Comment: Could [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37914099/how-to-change-device-compatibility-of-iphone-app-on-app-store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37914099/how-to-change-device-compatibility-of-iphone-app-on-app-store) help?

Comment: thanks,it help me!

Comment: I'll mark it as a duplicate then, since your problem sounded the same and is the same after receiving your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

There is not any direct way to specify compatible ios device. But you can use  [DeviceCompatibilityMatrix](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html) . You can specify hardware feature required. To allow app only on iphone, use following:

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
 <string>telephony</string>
 <string>gps</string>
 </array>
```

Telephonly not awailable on ipad and gps not available on ipod. So appstore will automatically remoev these from Compatible device list.

Comment: thank you ! i haven't see the result, but i think it's right

Comment: my newer app were rejected by Apple,because it's my 1.3.0 version ,  Apple think this kind of  change will make people  can't use the app they'v download before ,so  i want to know whether  i should  edit the compatibility information before my first app version release? thanks!